# What does this IE specific code do?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, comments

I was looking at [an article](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus) on how to detect focus in a browser window. Here's the [demo page](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/demo/2007-05-16-detect-browser-window-focus/).

I'm confused as to what this conditional does.

```
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```

I assume that `document.onfocusin` is an Internet Explorer equivalent of `window.onfocus`. But I don't understand what the conditional is doing:

```
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
```

Isn't this just a comment, which simplifies the expression to `if(false)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/8ka90k2e%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), the `@cc_on` statement allows IE to render something that other browsers are not. They call this, "conditional compilation".

> It is strongly recommended that you use the @cc_on statement in a comment, so that browsers that do not support conditional compilation will accept your script as valid syntax:
>
> An @if or @set statement outside of a comment also activates conditional compilation.

Therefore, IE will read the first condition of your code as `!false`, but every other browser will read it as `false`.

A warning, though:

> Conditional compilation is not supported in Internet Explorer 11 Standards mode and Windows Store apps.

Comment: Thanks! In addition, what does the trailing `@` do? Is that part of the syntax?

Comment: @AnubianNoob it closes the statement